# Why is scoped service instantiated multiple times?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

In my ConfigureServices I have a number of registered services for example:

```
services.AddScoped<IService1,Service1>();
services.AddScoped<IService2,Service2>();
services.AddScoped<IService3,Service3>();
```

If I now put a breakpoint on each one of the above I get expected behaviour which is that the breakpoint is hit once during startup as expected.

However I now have another service registered as follows:

```
    services.AddScoped<IWCFService>(service =>
    {
        using (var scope = service.CreateScope())
        {
            var settingData = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppSettingsDB>();
            var client = new WCFServiceClient(
                WCFServiceClient.EndpointConfiguration.WCF,
                settingData.Url);
            client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(
                new InspectorBehavior<IWCFServiceClient>(settingData.EnableLog));
            return client;
        };
    });
```

The above works fine however if I add a breakpoint I see its hit every time on every request.

Am I missing something or is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Some clarification needed. When you say *`hit every time on every request`*, do you mean for every place it is injected or for every HTTP request made to the api? Scoped lifetime means used once per HTTP request scope so that would be expected behavior

Comment: For every API request.  Did not observe that behaviour before so maybe its normal but other break points on other services don't get hit.

Answer (score 1):

That would be expected behavior as scoped lifetime means the object will be initialized once per request. So your implementation factor delegate will be called on each request to the API not each call to the service container (Transient).

Reference [Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes)

> ### Scoped
>
> Scoped lifetime services (AddScoped) are created once per client request (connection).

Comment: That might be correct I from my previous experience the container I believe was created at startup once.

Comment: Yes but factory delegate will be invoked for each request

Comment: I see.  The factory delegate does a lot of things like read data from database in order to create various services, that means this is happening for every request, The data is cached so not a big problem but any other ways to improve performance considering there might be 50 services created per request?